# How to use 2to3 to edit files in-place?

Tags: python, python-2to3

I am able to load the `2to3` file in Terminal. It does a lot of printing, with output like the following:

```
- print str
+ print(str)  ...
```

But the file is left without changes. And I don’t have any instructions after “run `2to3`”. Please help.

Answer (score 13):

If you [search for “2to3”](https://www.google.com/search?q=2to3) the first result is the [documentation for 2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html). As the documentation says, to overwrite the file instead of printing a diff, you just need to add the `-w` flag:

> [When you run the following:]
>
> ```
> $ 2to3 example.py
> ```
>
> A diff against the original source file is printed. 2to3 can also write the needed modifications right back to the source file. (A backup of the original file is made unless `-n` is also given.) Writing the changes back is enabled with the `-w` flag:
>
> ```
> $ 2to3 -w example.py
> ```